# Primefaces tool-tip for single star in rating

Tags: css, user-interface, primefaces

I was wondering if I could get some help with implementing a tool-tip for every single star in the ratings, using Primefaces. As of now, I have the tool-tip applying to the entire rating block, so all 5 stars have the same tool-tip in essence. Would anyone know of an elegant way to apply a different tool-tip to each star? Some of the people I work with have suggested using onHover() like states to do it if all else fails (in a rather brute forceish kind of way), but if possible, I'd like to do it with more elegance.

Here is the current code, which has a single tool-tip that pops up when any of the stars are hovered over.

```
<h:outputLabel for="developerScore">Developer Score:</h:outputLabel>
<p:rating value="#{scoreCard.developerScore}" stars="#{uiSettingsBean.ratingMax}" cancel="false" readonly="#{otherReadOnly}" id="developerScore">  
    <p:tooltip for="developerScore" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" >
         <h:outputText value="Developer Score Rubric"/><br />
         <h:outputText value="1 Star: Abysmal"/><br />
         <h:outputText value="2 Star: Needs Improvement"/><br />
         <h:outputText value="3 Star: Doing Good"/><br />
         <h:outputText value="4 Star: Above Average"/><br />
         <h:outputText value="5 Star: Exceptional"/>
    </p:tooltip>
</p:rating>
```

Anywho, any help is appreciated and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

I too had similar requirement and I landed to this SO and I was surprised to see that there is no accepted answer even after 3 years!

Primefaces(version 6.0) still does not have this feature. I hope it will be added in the next releases.

After doing a good bit of search, I Finally ended up creating a custom composite component.

Here is the solution/workaround that I have. It is elegant or not, I leave it to you :).

By the way, this works in JSF 2.2. For older version of JSF, you may have to add few more files for composite components to work.(taglibs etc).

First, we have to create our own composite component for rating (Don't worry, its just two files). It is nothing but the `p:rating` and `p:tooltip` combined together. Following are the two files:

1. **ratingComposite.xhtml**
2. **ratingComposite.js**

Add both the files to JSF resources folder of your project.
        (Note: customizedprimefaces is your resource library name)

```
<YourWarFile>\resources\customizedprimefaces\ratingComposite.xhtml     
<YourWarFile>\resources\js\ratingComposite.js
```

(If you are not familiar with composite components and their paths then I suggest to study it first, it is made easy in JSF 2.2.)

And start using it in your page.

**myPage.xhtml**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"*
        xmlns:cp="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/customizedprimefaces"
    >
...
<cp:ratingComposite id="ratingId" widgetVar="ratingIdWgt" 
    stars="4" 
    value="#{bean.rating}" 
    tooltipValue="Ugly | Bad | OK | Good"
 />
```

(Note the xmlns include: `xmlns:cp="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/customizedprimefaces"`)

This is same as the `p:rating` component with only difference is *tooltipValue* attribute that accepts a pipe separated tool tip messages in the order corresponding to the stars in rating.

### Here is the rough explanation of what is going on in javascript file:

1. Split the `p:tooltip` elements value by pipe(|) and save in an
   array(tooltipTxt), that holds pipe separated tooltips for each
   `<cp:ratingComposite/>` in page. The array is indexed by the rating component id.
2. Bind a custom *hoverIn* and *hoverOut* event handler for each star in
   your rating component.
3. On **hoverIn**, get the message from array(*tooltipTxt*) (at index corresponding to the currently hovered star) and replace with the `<p:tooltip>`
   message.
   Display the `<p:tooltip>` message at the position of the currently hovered star.
4. On **hoverOut**, Just hide the `<p:tooltip>` message.

**ratingComposite.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
   xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
   xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

   <composite:interface>
      <composite:attribute name="id"  />
      <composite:attribute name="value"  />
      <composite:attribute name="readonly"  />
      <composite:attribute name="widgetVar" />
      <composite:attribute name="stars" type="java.lang.Integer" />
      <composite:attribute name="tooltipValue"  
        shortDescription="A pipe(ie.:|) seperated list of tooltip messages. \nEach message in list corresponds to a star in the rating componant." />
    <!-- Add other attributes of p:rating component here. -->
   </composite:interface>

   <composite:implementation>
   <h:outputScript name="js/ratingComposite.js" target="head" />
   <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        $(document).ready(function(){
            rating.init('#{cc.namingContainer.clientId}:_#{cc.attrs.id}', '#{cc.namingContainer.clientId}:_#{cc.attrs.id}-ttId');
        });

    //-->
    </script>
     <p:rating id="_#{cc.attrs.id}" widgetVar="#{cc.attrs.widgetVar}" 
        readonly="#{cc.attrs.readonly}"
        value="#{cc.attrs.value}" stars="#{cc.attrs.stars}" />
    <p:tooltip id="_#{cc.attrs.id}-ttId" for="_#{cc.attrs.id}" trackMouse="true" 
    value="#{cc.attrs.tooltipValue}"  />
   </composite:implementation>
   </html>
```

**ratingComposite.js**

```
rating = {
        tooltipTxt:{},

        init:function(ratingId, tooltipId){
            var ratingIdjq = PrimeFaces.escapeClientId(ratingId);
            var tooltipIdjq = PrimeFaces.escapeClientId(tooltipId);
            var _self = this;
            this.tooltipTxt[tooltipId] = $(tooltipIdjq).find(".ui-tooltip-text").html(),

            $(ratingIdjq).find(".ui-rating-star").each(function(){
                $(this).hover(function(event){return _self.hoverIn(event,tooltipId)}, 
                                function(event){$(tooltipIdjq).hide();} //This is on Hoverout
                            );

            });
        },

        hoverIn:function(event, tooltipId){
            var tooltipIdjq = PrimeFaces.escapeClientId(tooltipId);
            var ratingArray = this.tooltipTxt[tooltipId].split("|");

            var tooptipDiv = $(tooltipIdjq);
            tooptipDiv.show();
            this.setCoordinate(tooptipDiv, event.pageX, event.pageY);
            var currEleIndx = $(event.currentTarget).parent().find(".ui-rating-star").index(event.currentTarget);
            var currTooltip = ratingArray[currEleIndx].trim();
            tooptipDiv.find(".ui-tooltip-text").html(currTooltip);
        },

        setCoordinate:function(tooptipDiv, x, y){
            var pos = {"left":x, "top":y};
            tooptipDiv.offset(pos);
        }

}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

use `<h:outputText value="1 Star:Abysmal:" title="1 Star: Abysmal"/>`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, but I'm not really sure how adding the title attribute fixes the problem. Could you explain further?